# Are properties of linear operators reflected in matrix reprsentations with different output and input basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a hermitian operator $ H $ ( $ H: V \to V $ ), and I write down its matrix representation in some basis ( same output and input basis ) $ B $,  $[H]_B$ then I know that transpose conjugate of $[H]_B$ is same as itself. But if I write the matrix representation with different input and output basis say $A$ and $B$ and let the matrix representation be $[H]_{AB}$ then is it still equal to its conjugate transpose?

I am asking this doubt because identity operator when written in same output input basis has a diagonal matrix representation with all ones along diagonal. But when the input output basis are different the identity operator has a matrix representation which is a unitary matrix. So are the properties of linear operator reflected in matrix representation only when written in same input output basis ?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the question

Comment: At any rate, the answer is that if $H$ is Hermitian, $[H]_{AB}$ is not necessarily Hermitian.  Note also that $[H]_B$ is only necessarily Hermitian if $B$ is orthonormal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry i was about to post another question forgot to change the title , will edit it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom if identity operator in represented in different orthonormal input output basis will the representation be unitary ? And if represented in non-orthonormal different output input basis ?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks i got it :)